# Handsontable - afterChangeEvent how to detect when a whole row is deleted or added

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I have create a custom function that executes on the afterChange cell event as per the instructions in the following Handsontable link.

https://docs.handsontable.com/0.15.0-beta3/Hooks.html

And I can perform actions based on each cell that is changed fine. As per the following code.

```
var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: data(),
    minSpareRows: 1,
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: ['some array of headers']
    afterChange: function (changes, source) {
          onChangeHandler(this, changes, source);
        }
});

var onChangeHandler = function (hot_instance, changes, source) {
      var changesLength;
      var changePayloadtoServer = [];
      if (changes != null) {
        changesLength = changes.length;
      } else {
        changesLength = 0;
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < changesLength; i++) {
        var row = changes[i][0],
            col = changes[i][1],
            oldVal = changes[i][2],
            newVal = changes[i][3],

        var trigger = false

        // How to I determine that a whole row has been deleted/added here?
        // trigger = some check that a whole row has been deleted/added.

        if (trigger == true) {
            // Perform action on row deletion
          // i.e. CASCADE DELETE query on database

          // Perform action on row addition
          // i.e. INSERT INTO query on database
        } else {
          // Perform normal on cell change
          // i.e. UPDATE query on database

        }

      }

}
```

However, I cant figure out how to determine whether a entire row has been deleted or added in the changes. Given that the change data provided in this afterChange event is in the follow format:

```
[
{changedRowNumber, chnagedColumnName, oldCellValue, newCellValue}
, {changedRowNumber, chnagedColumnName, oldCellValue, newCellValue}
, {changedRowNumber, chnagedColumnName, oldCellValue, newCellValue}
, {changedRowNumber, chnagedColumnName, oldCellValue, newCellValue}
, ... etc.
]
```

I have created an example fiddle. See link below.

https://jsfiddle.net/JoshAdams/go898kq6/

Does anyone know how I can detect when a whole row is added or deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is two other events also defined in the documentation:

- [afterCreateRow](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.15.0-beta3/Hooks.html#event:afterCreateRow)
- [afterRemoveRow](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.15.0-beta3/Hooks.html#event:afterRemoveRow)

As you can imagine, you will have to defiene this two events in your handsontable configuration and not in your afterChange event.

For example, see your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kcynt78y/) edited :

```
afterRemoveRow: function (index, amount) {
    console.log(amount + " row(s) removed starting line "+ index)
},
afterCreateRow: function (index, amount) {
    console.log(amount + " row(s) added starting line "+ index)
},
```

---

**EDIT :** Based on your comment, I made an example for the case you want; knowing when every value from a row became empty after a change.
You can find a new simplified [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/5yemxydb/) containg the following afterChange event definition :

```
hot.addHook('afterChange', function(changes) {
  if (!changes) {
     return;
  }
  $.each(changes, function (index, element) {
    var 
    rowEmpty = true,
    row = element[0],
    currentRowArray = hot.getData(row,0,row,hot.countCols());

    for(var i=0; i<currentRowArray[0].length-1; i++) {
      if(currentRowArray[0][i] != "") {
        rowEmpty = false;
        break;
      }
    }

    if(rowEmpty) {
      console.log("Row " + row + " is empty !");
    }
  });
});
```

Every time a change is made in a cell, the code within the event will check if there is at least one cell on the same row which contain a value (and finish the event if it sees one). If not, it prints in console that the row is empty. Hence the result you're looking for is the boolean *rowEmpty*.

*Also, note two things :*

1. The jQuery function ***$.each*** allows you to make it works when a user empty two (or more) rows at the same time.
2. The **-1** in the condition of the *for* loop. If you want to compare the length of your array versus the number of columns, don't forget that the number of columns obviously don't start to count from 0. So if there is 6 columns, this will be column 0 to 5, hence the **-1**.

Comment: thanks for the response. This somewhat answers my question. As your two events trigger when you select the 'remove row' and 'insert row' functions from the context menu. However, I would like to also detect the scenarios when "all data within the particular row is deleted" (i.e. someone highlights the row then hits DELETE on their keyboard) and when "there is no data currently in a particular row and a new value is input for the first time" (i.e. there is an empty row then someone enters the value 1 into the first column). Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Yes sure, with the afterChange event, if you use getData(row, row, col, col) (this function take 4 parameters because you can get a whole range of your table with it), you simply check if every value = "" of the currecnt row (where the change just happened). Do you want me to edit my answer with an example ? If it helps, I can provide one. (Probably not a full one though :))

Comment: sounds like a plan, could you provide an example though as suggested? :)

Comment: this is a fantastic solution, I only have one qualm which is that this event triggers 6 times (i.e. the number of columns there are), where it should only trigger once per row. I have marked it as a solution regardless as I can resolve this last part myself!

Comment: mmh yes I see, in fact it triggers 6 times if you empty 6 columns at the same time but only once if you empty 5 columns first, and delete the last one after. I'll try to take a look later, but do let me know if you fix the problem before :) (and why not also editing my answer of course)

Comment: no worries man. I'll update the answer if I get to it before you!